# Displaying a large amount of data from Core Data

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad

I have such a task in front of me: there are more than 10,000 records in the database, I need to display them in the table view, but I can not take all 10,000 and store in the array how to organize the work, for example, when scrolling 100 records in a table view, Download the next 100 entries from the database.

I found things like fetchLimit and fetchOffset, but I still did not understand how to use them for my task.

What would you tell me?

Comment: if you get a chance go through https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsfetchrequest#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFetchRequest/fetchOffset document, that will help you a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe if you are using Core Data and you need `UITableView` you should defiantly use `NSFetched​Results​Controller`.

From Apple documentation.

> You use a fetched results controller to efficiently manage the results
>   returned from a Core Data fetch request to provide data for a
>   UITable​View object.

By using of this approach you going to use by default Cache that will improve performance. Also with this you going to dynamically update `UITableView` when some of the records in Core Data will be changed or be added.

Also to fetch data by portion you can modify `NSFetchRequest` and set`fetchLimit` for each request.

[Example](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/03/05/displaying-data-with-nsfetchedresultscontroller-and-swift/) of the simple `NSFetched​Results​Controller` implementation.